# Create instances and pass to the constructors or create inside the constructor?

Tags: javascript, require

I am not sure which I should follow. I started using require.js and started seeing that instances are not visible. So I have 2 options: create and pass to the other constructor or create them inside the class. For example:

```
define
    dep1,
    dep2
    dep3

dep1 = new Dep1
dep2 = new Dep2
dep3 = new Dep3(dep1, dep2)
```

or

should I do somtihg like this

```
define(dep3) 

dep3 = new Dep3();
```

in dep3 file:

```
define(dep1, dep2);

dep3.initialize: function() {
   this.dep1 = new Dep1;
   this.dep2 = new Dep2;
}
```

Code is very abstract but I hope you get the idea. So which option and when should I use?

Answer (score 1):

if you always just want to create dep3 and every instance of dep3 should have its own references to dep1/2, you should go with the 2nd approach.

If you want to share Dep1 or Dep2 between multiple Del3 instances, you should pass it via constructor.

Its really up to you, in terms of logic for the Dep3 instance there is no difference...